# TensorFlowModel deployments Error, dependencies from provided requirements.txt not installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to deploy a TensorFlowModel and provide the post processing in an inference.py file...

I previously managed to deploy the model and invoke it in a notebook and then do the post processing in a jupyter notebook with the following code:

```
model = TensorFlowModel(
    name=name_from_base('tf-yolov4'),
    model_data=model_artifact,
    role=role,
    framework_version='2.3'
)
```

now i want to do the post processing by providing an inference.py file so i followed the docs here:
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/using_tf.html#sagemaker-tensorflow-docker-containers

and used this snippet:

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlowModel

model = TensorFlowModel(entry_point='inference.py',
                        dependencies=['requirements.txt'],
                        model_data='s3://mybucket/model.tar.gz',
                        role='MySageMakerRole')
```

**The dependencies i added**:

```
numpy
tensorflow
```

**My problem is**:
the deployment process when i call

```
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge')
```

doesn't complete, and when i checked cloud watch i found the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 162, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 414, in <module>
    resources = ServiceResources()
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 400, in __init__
    self._python_service_resource = PythonServiceResource()
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 83, in __init__
    self._handler, self._input_handler, self._output_handler = self._import_handlers()
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 278, in _import_handlers
    spec.loader.exec_module(inference)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy as np
```

and

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

which led me to believe that my inference.py was used by the container but not the requirements.txt file i provided therefore No module named 'numpy'!

**My question:**
what am i doing wrong with my code and how to make sure the dependencies to run inference.py are installed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A: SageMaker requires your model artifacts to be compressed in a .tar.gz file. SageMaker automatically extracts this .tar.gz file into the /opt/ml/model/ directory in your container. If you are making use of one of the framework containers, such as TensorFlow, PyTorch, or MXNet, the container expects your TAR structure to be as follows:
*TensorFlow*

```
model.tar.gz/
             |--[model_version_number]/|--variables|--saved_model.pb
            code/
                |--inference.py|--requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your resposne!

when I structure my model .tar file as you mentioned, and don't specify entry_point argument and dependencies argument..

it completely ignores my code/ directory and does not use my inference.py or requirements.txt file.